# Blender 2.8 My soil shader looks too glossy

Tags: shaders, pbr, reflection

I'm trying to do a soil material using the following textures:

https://texturehaven.com/tex/?t=coral_ground_02

I applied a 'displaced' modifier and built the shader nodes but my surface looks too bright and glossy
[image]

The material in the site looks more rough and appears to have the rocks on the model, but in mine looks like mud. I watched several tutorials and tried to change several values on my node set and I can't get it right.

Here is my node set. Could anyone help me to take off this glossy aspect?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to set a brighter color to your color ramp, and try playing with the position of the handles. Pure black makes glossy, pure white makes rough.

Comment: Damm it man, you are right! Thanks for the answer!